# How to fix a problem in Android Studio build (update Firebase)

Tags: android, firebase

My problem is about firebase versions when I add the last line   "implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'" I get this problem

This is my code :

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'me.zhanghai.android.materialratingbar:library:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'com.github.sharish:ShimmerRecyclerView:v1.1'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0'
implementation 'com.github.ivbaranov:materiallettericon:0.2.3'
implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
```

Comment: I don't see any errors tho ..

Comment: What is the error that you are getting.?

Comment: thank you for rypling me this error : error: cannot access zzbgl
class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbgl not found

Comment: So you better to paste **the logcat** in the question...Otherwise, can't help you I'm afraid.

Comment: i  didn't understand please can you explain ?

Comment: You need to show us all of your logs including and surround your error.

Answer (score 0):

I think that

```
'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
```

need to be, before other firebase dependencies!

And the last version of firebase-core is 16.0.3, Android Studio warns this.

In the final of app.gradle include:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Try clean project and rebuild project, if this didn't work, post here the build errors.

Comment: error: cannot access zzbgl
class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbgl not found

Comment: when i tried to change implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1' with implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1' i dont have a problem in build but the app dont work

Comment: Check if your sdk repository is with dependencies updated! In SDK Tools "Google Play services", and other packages.

Comment: Hello, all is updated but i have always the same problem :/ can you help me pleaaaase

Comment: i tired to change  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'  by implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1' the build is complet successfully but the app dont work fine, but when i use 16.0.1 i got the error and build not finish

Comment: Area you closing the tag: **dependencies {** ?